# When using VS Code for Python, is there a Workspace functionality like in MATLAB?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to run my code and then play with some of its outputs after the fact, but nothing is saved to my cmd or Python shells. I have just been running the entire thing and adding some debug code at the end, but it takes too long and feels clunky.

Comment: what is `Workspace functionality in MATLAB` ?  We may know Python but not MATLAB.

Comment: maybe you should run code in [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) ? Probably It can works like "Workspace"

Comment: You may also want to consider [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) if you want a Matlab-like GUI for python.

Comment: matlab's workspace is a docked window in the IDE where you can see variable names, some of their attributes, and you can click on them to inspect tables and matrices

Comment: Both [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) and the [scientific mode of Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html) give you a full "IDE" feeling of notebooks